# Formatting numbers with localized thousands separators and decimal precision in python

Tags: python, string-formatting

It is possible to format a number with decimal precision with :

```
print("{:.2f}".format(7654321.234567))
```

It is possible to format a number with localized thousands separators with :

```
import locale
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, '')
print("{:n}".format(7654321.234567))
```

But how can I do both at the same time?

I would like to print `7 654 321.23` in a country where thousands separator is the space for instance and `7,654,321.23` in a country where thousands separator is the comma? But I cannot know in advance what the localized separator will be.

Comment: Does the update meet your requirement?

Comment: Almost. A perfect solution would be usable in a Jinja environment (i.e. without an intermediary var like `my_sep`). But I am not sure it is even possible just playing with `format`. I will accept your answer in a few days if there is no other answer!

Comment: Ah, there's Jinja. Why not keep `my_sep` as a context variable then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a comma - the thousands separator - before the dot, and do a replace with the appropriate separator of your locale:

```
>>> my_sep = locale.localeconv()['thousands_sep']
>>> print("{:,.2f}".format(7654321.234567).replace(',', my_sep))
7 654 321.23
```